# File not found error during asset precompilation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, summernote

I'm trying to deploy a rails app to an elastic-beanstalk server, the deploy fails due to an error during the precompilation process.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: summernote-custom-theme.min.
```

and here's the import in application.scss

```
@import "summernote-custom-theme.min";
```

I'm including the summernote-rails gem in my Gemfile.

Why am I getting this error & how can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says you have to import styles like this:

```rb
@import "bootstrap";
@import "summernote-bs4";
```

Readme hasn't changed since June 2019.